# How to set interval to always last Xs when clicked on carousel button (vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, carousel, setinterval, intervals

I have made custom carousel (for learning) on this web page. Carousel has 2 buttons (next and previous) and dots (each dot is 1 picture). It all works fine, but there is one problem. I want to make automatic loop carousel (to loop through images in interval of X seconds). Now i am using `setInterval(nextImgShow, 2000);`. But every time i click on either button (next, previous, dots) the interval changes.

Example: I have interval of 2s. If i click on a button when 1,5s has passed, the next image will only show for 0,5s. If i click it right away at 0,5s, the next image will show for 1,5s.

I already try to fix this with `clearInterval();`, but it does not change a thing. I also try to use `clearInterval();` and than set interval again `setInterval(nextImgShow, 2000);` (on every button), but no luck.
I also try to use `setTimeout();` but again nothing.

My wish is: If interval is 2s, when i click on either of buttons, i want to reset/set my interval back to 2s. So that every image is displayed for 2s, no matter when the button was clicked.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Below is JavaScript code and link to my web page, so you can see.

LINK: [Link to page, so you can see demo](https://www.jernejtratnik.com/urban/)

```js
// navigation selection
const navigation = document.querySelector("ul.navigation");
const navigationToggleButton = document.querySelector(".navigation-toggle");
const navigationList = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation a");
// background image selector
const backgroundImgDiv = document.querySelector(".bg");
const previousImgBtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextImgBtn = document.querySelector(".next");
const imgDotBtn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dot"));
const arrImg = ['url("img/0.jpg")', 'url("img/1.jpg")', 'url("img/2.jpg")', 'url("img/3.jpg")'];
const dot0 = document.querySelector(".dot-0");
const dot1 = document.querySelector(".dot-1");
const dot2 = document.querySelector(".dot-2");
const dot3 = document.querySelector(".dot-3");
let startImgIndex = 0;
let currentIndex = 0;

// navigation functions
function toggleNav() {
    navigation.classList.toggle("active");
}
 
function navLink() {
    navigation.classList.remove("active");
}

// background image functions
function nextImgShow() {
    startImgIndex++;
    if (startImgIndex === arrImg.length) {
        startImgIndex = 0;
    }
    currentIndex = startImgIndex;
    backgroundImgDiv.style.backgroundImage = arrImg[startImgIndex];
    toggleDotActive(currentIndex);
}

function previousImgShow() {
    startImgIndex--;
    if (startImgIndex === -1) {
        startImgIndex = (arrImg.length - 1);
    }
    currentIndex = startImgIndex;
    backgroundImgDiv.style.backgroundImage = arrImg[startImgIndex];
    toggleDotActive(currentIndex);
}

function dotBtnNavigate() { 
    if (this.classList.contains("dot-0")) {
        dotBtnSet(0);
    } else if (this.classList.contains("dot-1")) {
        dotBtnSet(1);
    } else if (this.classList.contains("dot-2")) {
        dotBtnSet(2);
    } else if (this.classList.contains("dot-3")) {
        dotBtnSet(3);   
    }
}

function dotBtnSet (number) {
    backgroundImgDiv.style.backgroundImage = arrImg[number];
    startImgIndex = number;
    currentIndex = number;
    toggleDotActive(currentIndex);
}

function toggleDotActive(currentIndex) {
    switch(currentIndex) {
        case 0:
            dot0.classList.add("dot-active");
            dot1.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot2.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot3.classList.remove("dot-active");
            break;
        case 1:
            dot0.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot1.classList.add("dot-active");
            dot2.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot3.classList.remove("dot-active");
            break;
        case 2:
            dot0.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot1.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot2.classList.add("dot-active");
            dot3.classList.remove("dot-active");
            break;
        case 3:
            dot0.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot1.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot2.classList.remove("dot-active");
            dot3.classList.add("dot-active");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// navigation events
navigationToggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
navigationList.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", navLink));

// background image event
nextImgBtn.addEventListener("click", nextImgShow)

previousImgBtn.addEventListener("click", previousImgShow);
imgDotBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", dotBtnNavigate));

// for touch devices (carousel navigate)
const gestureZone = document.querySelector('.img-wrap');
let touchstartX = 0;
let touchstartY = 0;
let touchendX = 0;
let touchendY = 0;

// for touch devices function (carousel navigate)
function handleGesture() {
    if (touchendX <= touchstartX) {
        nextImgShow();
    }
    
    if (touchendX >= touchstartX) {
        previousImgShow();
    }
}

setInterval(nextImgShow, 2000);
// navigation events
navigationToggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
navigationList.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", navLink));

// background image event
nextImgBtn.addEventListener("click", nextImgShow);
previousImgBtn.addEventListener("click", previousImgShow);
imgDotBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", dotBtnNavigate));

// for touch devices events (carousel navigate)
gestureZone.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    touchstartX = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    touchstartY = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;
}, false);

gestureZone.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
    touchendX = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    touchendY = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;
    handleGesture();
}, false);
```

Comment: If you're providing a code snippet, please attach the HTML, too.

Comment: when you tried using `clearInterval();` did you pass in the intervalID retuned from the setInterval() function?

Comment: Why you're using two variables, `startImgIndex` and `currentIndex`, that are the same?

Comment: You're attaching the events of the navigation and images buttons twice!

Comment: Please display our your code with `clearIntervel()` (the important sections).

Comment: @AndrewLohr I cant figure out what should the intervalID be in my case. 
When I used `clearIntervel()` I did something like this on every button:
`setInterval(nextImgShow, 2000);
clearIntervel()`

Comment: @חייםפרידמן This is the example of the "next" button with `clearIntervel()` :
`
function nextImgShow() {
    startImgIndex++;
    if (startImgIndex === arrImg.length) {
        startImgIndex = 0;
    }
    currentIndex = startImgIndex;
    backgroundImgDiv.style.backgroundImage = arrImg[startImgIndex];
    toggleDotActive(currentIndex);
    clearInterval();
    setInterval(nextImgShow, 2000);

}
`

Comment: @Jerry You must assign the `setInterval` to a variable like this: `var intvl = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);` and clear it like this: `clearInterval(intvl)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing the interval ID (returned from setInterval) to the clear interval function. For example:

`let myIntervalID = setInterval(nextImgShow, 2000);`

Then you can clear the interval doing `clearInterval(myIntervalID)` just make sure the variable `myIntervalID` is in scope when you clear it.

Your clearInterval wasn't actually clearing the interval so you ran into this problem. Once you correctly clear the interval (like above) and call the interval again (kinda like resetting the interval) your image will show for the full interval

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the `setInterval` to a variable and use `clearInterval` when the user clicks on one of the buttons to change the image and then set the interval again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var change;
var i = 1;
var numOfImages = 3;
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById("img1").classList.add("active");
  change = setInterval(function(){
    changeImage();
  }, 2000);
});
function changeImage(){
 var elem = document.getElementById("img"+i);
    elem.style.display = "none";
    i++;
    if(i>numOfImages){
     i = 1;
    }
    var elemToBeShown = "#img"+i;
    $(elemToBeShown).show();
}
</script>
<style>
.images{
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
#img2{
  display: none;
}
#img3{
  display: none;
}
.button{
 border-radius: 50%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    margin: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
.button:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="images">
<img id="img1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="125" height="125"/>
<img id="img2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="125" height="125"/>
<img id="img3" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkoieaGln2U5aMZQZibEmbva3LVpVVOw-GbcizRKfmZzog4B5lnw" width="125" height="125"/>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top: 25px;">
<div class="button" id="button1"></div>
<div class="button" id="button2"></div>
<div class="button" id="button3"></div>
</div>
<script>
$('.button').click(function(e){
 var buttonid = $(this).attr('id');
    var imgid = parseInt(buttonid.substring(6, buttonid.length), 10);
    if(i!=imgid){
     clearInterval(change);
        document.getElementById("img"+i).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("img"+imgid).style.display = "block";
        i = imgid;
        change = setInterval(function(){
       changeImage();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```